# Accessing files from Windows Store App

Tags: windows-store-apps

I'm working in Windows 8 Operating System building Windows Store apps.

I'm trying to access one XML file(present within the solution) via the code below.

```
var file = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(@"E:\Gowtham\Data.xml");
```

But I'm getting "Access to the path 'E:\Gowtham\Data.xml' is denied.'" exception.

I tried all possible ways to remove the read-only attribute of the folder and the file but no use.

I used command prompt to change the attributes of the file, also I tried manually but the read-only attribute of that folder is not changed.

Kind help pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get ANY file like that way. I highly recommend you to read these links. You can access files from library if you have declared library access capability.

[File system places accessible through WinRT API](http://lunarfrog.com/blog/2012/05/21/winrt-folders-access/)

[Windows 8: The right way to Read & Write Files in WinRT](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html)