# How to open .txt and .docx and .xls document in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, app-launcher

How do I open text document, .docx and .xls document in windows phone 8,
I am saving file in isolated storage then trying to open using Launcher.FileAsync but do not getting the result. For more information, see my code below:

```
  string file = "Download.txt";
  IsolatedStorageFileStream isfStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(file, FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication());

        isfStream.Close();


        StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync(file);

        Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);
```

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791369/accessing-files-from-windows-store-app).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of `GetFileAsync()` is

```
public IAsyncOperation<StorageFile> GetFileAsync(string name)
```

where

**name** : The name (or path *relative* to the current folder) of the file to get.

your string is

```
string file = "Download.txt";
```

This might not be accepted as a relative path. Try something like,

```
string file = @"\Download.txt";
```

Comment: Karthik, I got the solutiuon, I was trying to launch before completely download it. So, it was corrupting it. I have done it using background downloader, and then launch it. Thanks